# Problem with PostgresSQL password authentication failed for user when trying to access or fetch data from database?

Tags: postgresql, docker, .net-core

I have an issue when trying to fetch data from postgressql. I'm playing with microservices arhitecture using  .NET Core 5.0 and postgressql as my db solution.

I'm trying to containerize my app by using docker containers. And everything works fine till I try to fetch some data through  API.

I got this type of error:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 28P01: password authentication failed for user "admin"
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.AuthenticateMD5(String username, Byte[] salt, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Authenticate(String username, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<<Rent>g__RentAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryRowAsync[T](IDbConnection cnn, Row row, Type effectiveType, CommandDefinition command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.Async.cs:line 472
```

From the backend prespective, situation is pretty simple where I'm trying to fetch data by productName:

```
public async Task<Coupon> GetDiscount(string productName)
    {
        using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection
            (_configuration.GetValue<string>("DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString"));

        var coupon = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Coupon>
            ("SELECT * FROM Coupon WHERE ProductName = @ProductName", new { ProductName = productName });

        if (coupon == null)
            return new Coupon 
            { ProductName = "No Discount", Amount = 0, Description = "No Discount Desc" };

        return coupon;
    }
```

My appsettings.json file, or to be more precise connection string towards postgressql is this:

```
 "DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"
  },
```

In docker compose override yml file I have:

```
discountdb:
    container_name: discountdb
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=admin
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin1234
      - POSTGRES_DB=DiscountDb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

And as I can see, in my portainer I can see that discountdb is up and running
[image]

I'm missing something and I don't know what.

Comment: Well, either there is no password set or one different from the one you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to update your connection string when running your application in a container. I assume you can't reach the db.

You are referencing **localhost** from within the app according to `appsettings.json`, unless you have overridden the connection string. And localhost in the container is it's own context.

So, your connection string looks like this.

```
"Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"
```

But it should probably look like this (the docker network from docker compose will resolve the name):

```
"Server=discountdb;Port=5432;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"
```

So in your docker compose file under your `pgadmin` service, you can add an environment section if you don't have it already, to override the connection string.

```
environment:
  - DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString="Server=discountdb;Port=5432;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"
```

Should maybe be without the `"` in the override.

Answer (score 4):

Check if you have a PostgreSQL instance running on your computer then stop from service and it will work fine lm using the same tutorial and stopped my locally installed postgressql service

Comment: How do you find and stop the postgressql service?

Answer (score 2):

I Found the solution for me first in appsettings.json add the server name (probably will be the postgres database container name) and the Host=localhost:

```
 "DatabaseSettings": {
  "ConnectionString": "Server=discountdb;Port=5432;Host=localhost;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"
 
},
```

then you need to check if has any server running with port 5432 usually if you have Postgres install in your computer the default port is 5432 so you need to stop it.

command to kill if you're using windows:

```
taskkill /PID <port value> /F
```

then run the application again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have another instance of PostgreSQL running locally on your computer on 5432 port. So you are calling this server instead of your containerized one.
On the other hand Portainer runs inside your docker-compose network and calls containerized service as expected.
You can try to set different port in your docker-compose file.

Comment: If any other process is using the port 5432 then Docker is not able to run the container at this port. However the container is running.

Comment: For some reason docker-compose up do not throw error in this case. Same issue on macos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108226/local-postgres-app-running-on-port-5432-but-docker-compose-service-mapped-to-th
And I also run into this behaviour on win10

Answer (score 1):

I  got the same issue, and I spend more than 1 week trying to look at the solutions. I thought we follow the same tutorial because when I read your code this is exactly like my one.
Well for my just I changed the file "appsettings.json"

"Server=your name of your PC;Port=5432;Database=DiscountDb;User Id=admin;Password=admin1234;"

Don't use localhost replace for the name of your PC.

Comment: This solution is aready proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68000885/5320906).  When answering old questions, please ensure that your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, ı deleted postgesql (not docker) in my local machine. And resolved. Because my local postgre password is not same docker password. so it say password not true

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I have **removed** PostgreSQL Db from my own **local** machine because I suggest that I had configured the another password when add local PostgreSQL Db.
I'm using Docker at the moment, and it's not necessary to use local Db.